# How to stack two pandas dataframe and not loosing column names?

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge, concatenation

I have two very different pandas DataFrames with unique column names. And I want to stack them one under another.Nothing else like "union" or "intersection" needed. Like "copy paste" one under another. And I also don't want to lose any column names.

**Df1:**

```
  Col1
1  A    C
2  B    D
3  X    Y
```

**DF2:**

```
    Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
   1  a   c    x    t
   2  b   d    y    j
   3  b   e    z    k
```

I tried using pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=0, ignore_index = True) but this resulted in something like this:

```
  Col1
1  A   C      Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan
2  B   D      Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan
3  X   Y      Nan   Nan   Nan   Nan
4  Nan Nan   Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5
5  Nan Nan    a     c      x     t
6  Nan Nan    b     b      y     j
7  Nan Nan    b     e      z     k
```

**Expected Result:**

```
  Col1
1  A     C     Nan    Nan
2  B     D     Nan    Nan
3  X     Y     Nan    Nan
4 Col2  Col3 Col4   Col5
5  a     c     x      t
6  b     b     y      j
7  b     e     z      k
```

Original DFs

**DF1**
[image]

**DF2**
[image]

Comment: can you provide your dataframes as constructors? You input is quite ambiguous (if the second column label of `df1` empty?)

Comment: @ScottBoston Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @mozway Second column label is empty. That's not a mistake. If that's really necessary I can share my original DataFrames. But the examples I shared above are almost identical to the original structure.

Comment: I didn't build the DFs by myself I just read two CSV files to create them. @ScottBoston

Comment: @Baran Unlike the corresponding dataframe in the example you provided, `DF1` in your image has header `[0,1,2,...,9]`, not anything like `['Col1','']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas does not allow for multiple unnamed columns (i.e. columns with the empty string as a name) since column names must be unique. That said, I think this gets close to your desired result.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':[*'ABX'],'':[*'CDY']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Col2':[*'abb'],'Col3':[*'cde'],'Col4':[*'xyz'],'Col5':[*'tjk']})

mat1 = np.vstack([df1.columns,df1.to_numpy()])
mat2 = np.vstack([df2.columns,df2.to_numpy()])

df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(mat1),pd.DataFrame(mat2)])
```

The resulting dataframe `df` is

```
      0     1     2     3
0  Col1         NaN   NaN
1     A     C   NaN   NaN
2     B     D   NaN   NaN
3     X     Y   NaN   NaN
0  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5
1     a     c     x     t
2     b     d     y     j
3     b     e     z     k
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a weird reshape. You can't directly move the header as row, but a trick is to `reset_index` on the transpose.

For the `concat`, set aside the column header and put it back:

```
cols = df1.columns
(pd.concat([df1.set_axis(range(df1.shape[1]), axis=1),
            df2.T.reset_index().T], ignore_index=True)
   .rename(columns=dict(enumerate(cols))))
```

output:

```
   Col1           2     3
0     A     C   NaN   NaN
1     B     D   NaN   NaN
2     X     Y   NaN   NaN
3  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5
4     a     c     x     t
5     b     d     y     j
6     b     e     z     k
```